# Eslint warning loop with useMemo, initialization of variable using a hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

Trying to figure out how to make ESlint happy with my Typescript code. It seems like I'm using some kind of anti-pattern based on the ESlint warnings and errors below.

My component that compares a provided prop object `credential` with a parent Formik form object `values`. It uses a Hook to get an array of provinces to index using the code stored in the `credential`:

```
import {
  FunctionComponent,
  PropsWithChildren,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
} from 'react'
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik'

type Province = {
  id: number
  code: string
  name: string
}

type Credential = {
  name: string
  designation: string
  province: Province
}

type Props = {
  credential?: Credential
}

const FormComponent: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({ credential }) => {
  const { values } = useFormikContext()
  const provinces = useSupportedProvinces() ?? []
  const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState<boolean>(true)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (credential) {
      Object.entries(values).map(([formKey, formValue]) => {
        if (formKey === 'province') {
          const provId = provinces.find(
            ({ code }) => code === credential.province.code,
          )?.id

          if (provId !== formValue) {
            setIsButtonDisabled(false)
          } else {
            setIsButtonDisabled(true)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }, [])
}
```

We include `provinces` in the dep array of the useEffect, which leads to this warning:

```
The 'provinces' logical expression could make the dependencies
 of useEffect Hook (at line 25) change on every render. 
To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'provinces' 
in its own useMemo() Hook.
```

Easy enough, let's do it!

```
const provinces = useMemo(() => useSupportedProvinces() ?? [], [])
```

Uh oh! ESlint has upgraded our warning to an error:

```
React Hook "useSupportedProvinces" cannot be called inside 
a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React 
function component or a custom React Hook function.
```

Now we're back where we started

What is the correct way to initialize the `provinces` array here? A way that does not break any React rules.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the conditional expression is actually the cause of the 1st warning - it pays to read the warning multiple times.

The code would cause the `useEffect` to be triggered multiple times.

```js
const provinces = useSupportedProvinces()

...

const provId = provinces?.find(
  ({ code }) => code === credential.province.code,
)?.id;
```

Removing the conditional `?? []` in the initializer and checking elsewhere solved the issue.